# A better and clean way to do it between relationships?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm on an API development, and I'm getting the results I'm looking for, but I don't think is the clean and best way to do this code between some relationships, and would like to read suggestions for a better way to do.

I'm looking for the results of timing tracks on a range of two dates and an user.

We have three tables / models:
- users
- trips (with the field user_id)
- tracks (with the field trip_id)

Important to know: the tracks table has two dates on each row, 'start_datetime' and 'stop_datetime'.

My code:

```
// We get all the 'trip_id' from the dates range
$alltracks = Track::whereBetween('start_datetime', [$datefrom, $dateto])->orWhereBetween('stop_datetime', [$datefrom, $dateto])->pluck('trip_id')->toArray();

// We get all the 'trips_id' of the user $id on the range
$trips = Trip::where('user_id', $id)->whereIn('id', $alltracks)->pluck('id')->toArray();

// If we have results, we check again to get the right tracks
if ($trips != null) {
    $tracks = Track::whereBetween('start_datetime', [$datefrom, $dateto])
    ->orWhereBetween('stop_datetime', [$datefrom, $dateto])
    ->whereIn('trip_id', $trips)
    ->orderBy('start_datetime', 'ASC')->get();
} else {
    return response()->json(['status' => 404, 'message' => 'There are no trips on this range for this driver'], 404);
}
```

I get the results that I'm looking for, but it's making me crazy do 3 queries for the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in one query using an inner join. To use a [join in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#joins) you use the DB Facade.

```
//Using the DB facade
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

To get the tracks you want:

```
$tracks = DB::table('tracks')
              ->select('tracks.*','trips.*') //select needed columns
              ->join('trips','trips.id','=','tracks.trip_id')
              ->whereBetween('tracks.start_datetime', [$datefrom, $dateto])
              ->orWhereBetween('tracks.stop_datetime', [$datefrom, $dateto])
              ->where('trips.user_id',$id)
              ->orderBy('tracks.start_datetime', 'ASC')
              ->get();
```

The get method returns an Illuminate\Support\Collection containing the results where each result is an instance of the PHP stdClass object.

Comment: Thanks. This is a pretty code, but the where's are confused, this is the right code that works perfectly:

      ->where('trips.user_id',$id)
      ->where(function ($query) use ($datefrom, $dateto) {$query
        ->whereBetween('tracks.start_datetime', [$datefrom, $dateto])
        ->orWhereBetween('tracks.stop_datetime', [$datefrom, $dateto]);

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have this kind of relationships between the tables

`User -> hasMany -> Trips -> hasMany -> Tracks`

Then you can try this (not tested but the idea is this):

```
# App\User.php

public function trips()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Trip::class);
}

# App\Trip.php

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function tracks()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Track::class);
}

# App\Track.php

public function trip()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Trip::class);
}

# SomethingController.php

public function findByUser($user_id)
{
    $datefrom = ...
    $dateto = ...

    $tracks = Track::whereBetween('start_datetime', [$datefrom, $dateto])
        ->orWhereBetween('stop_datetime', [$datefrom, $dateto])
        ->with('trip.user' => function($qry) use ($user_id) {
            $qry->where('id' => $user_id);
        })->get();

    // now you have the tracks

    // additionally to get the trips, see below
    $trips = [];
    if (!$tracks->isEmpty()) {
        $trips = $tracks->map(function($track) {
            return $track->trip;
        });
    }

    ....
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a good use case of [hasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) eloquent relationship.
You can try this:

Define `hasManyThrough` relationship on `User` model:

```php
public function tracks()
{
     return $this->hasManyThrough(Track::class, Trip::class);
}
```

In `Controller`:

```php
User::whereId($id)->first()
   ->tracks()
     ->whereBetween('tracks.start_datetime', [$datefrom, $dateto])
     ->orWhereBetween('tracks.stop_datetime', [$datefrom, $dateto])
     ->orderBy('tracks.start_datetime', 'ASC')
   ->get();
// It gives you all the tracks taken by the underlying user
// within the defined conditions
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Strange to see downvote on this. There should be a valid reason when someone downvotes an answer.